# Deleting an object with Ajax in Django not working

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a Django template : home.html page:

```
<a href="#" class = "dept" contextmenu = "mymenu2" id = "{{d.dept.id}}"    ><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> {{d.dept}} <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>

<ul class='custom-menu2'>
  <p><a id = "add_emp">Add new Employee</a></p> <br>

  <p><a class = "del_dept">Delete this Deptartment</a></p>

</ul> 

<script>
var id;

  $('.dept').mousedown(function(event) {
   switch (event.which) {
    case 3:
      id = $(this).attr('id');


       $('.del_dept').on('click',function(e){

            if(e.handled !== true)
            {
             alert(id);
               $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "del_dept",
                     data: { 'id':id },
                     success: function(response){
                     alert(response.success);
            }
            });
                 return false;
             e.handled = true; 
            }                
       });          

       break;
}
});

</script>
```

views.py:

```
def del_dept(request):
    department = Department.objects.get(pk = int(request.REQUEST['id']))
    print department
    print ("ABCD")
    department.delete()
    payload = {'success': True}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(payload), content_type='application/json')
```

main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^employee/', include('EmployeeManagement.urls')),
    )
```

and the EmployeeManagement.urls file:

```
  urlpatterns = [
     # ex: /polls/
     url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
     url(r'^(?P<emp_id>[-\w]+)/$', views.get_employee,     name='get_employee'),
     url(r'^(?P<emp_id>[-\w]+)/(?P<status>[-\w]+)/$', views.change_status, name='change_status'),
     url(r'save_dept$',views.save_dept, name = 'save_dept'),
     url(r'save_emp$',views.save_emp, name = 'save_emp'),
     url(r'del_dept$',views.del_dept, name = 'del_dept'),
```

]

Don't know whats wrong, Apprantly, when i click on the **'Delete this Department'** button, the id of that specific department alerts but after that nothing happens. Also in **del_dept view**, i tried to print department and just some text for test but nither of them is printing.

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax url isn't a valid url

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "{% url 'del_dept' %}",
         data: { 'id':id },
         beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
         },
         success: function(response){
         alert(response.success);
        }
        });
```

Note I have changed `del_dept` to use the django url template tag. You may need to include a namespace here but it doesn't look like you do from what you have shown

For post requests, you will also need to include a [csrf token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax).

Also, your view is looking in the wrong place for the id, post data goes into `request.POST` so your query becomes the following

```
department = Department.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST['id']))
```

You may not need to cast the id as an int since it might already be one.

Comment: Also, whilst not part of your question, I would recommend using a [login required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) or other decorators so that users must be at least logged in to start deleting things from your database

Comment: It is going into that del_dept view but still not printing "ABCD" and the department name. plus still nothing happens after it alerts the id

Comment: @MirzaTaimoorBaig - Sorry missed that bit at first, updated my answer, you were looking in the wrong request dict

Comment: I already tried it before you updated the answer, still wouldn't work. Here what happens in the console box, it loads the employee main page: ** "GET employee/....** and when Delete this Department clicked: **POST employee/del_dept...** loads, it prints nothing on console and deletion doesn't occur

Comment: @MirzaTaimoorBaig - How are you debugging this exactly? Are you using Pycharm? is `DEBUG` set to true in settings? does it work if you send a `GET` request instead (update the query to use a random id)? Its hard to figure out what the problem could be otherwise. I'm guessing there isn't a pk with the value of `id`, maybe you were looking for getting the department whos `id=..POST['id']`

Comment: Its Working now, there just a bit of mistake in syntax.

Comment: And No, Im using Sublime. Ain't got no key for PyCharm

Comment: @MirzaTaimoorBaig - Glad its working now, I only asked as PyCharm would allow you to set breakpoints and inspect variables (I haven't really used Sublime all that much). There is a free community edition of it too. For completeness, eclipse would also let you do this, but I really don't like eclipse

Comment: Ohh sure. Thanks for help.